# How to Don't Repeat Yourself with Swift 2.0 enums

Tags: enums, swift2

I've got multiple enums with raw values, but I don't like having to say `rawValue:` every time I initialize one from a raw value, so I've supplied an alternative delegating initializer with no external label:

```
enum E1 : Int {
    case One, Two
    init?(_ what:Int) {
        self.init(rawValue:what)
    }
}
enum E2 : Int {
    case One, Two
    init?(_ what:Int) {
        self.init(rawValue:what)
    }
}
```

Very nice. I can say `let e = E1(0)` and the right thing happens.

Now I'd like to consolidate the repeated code. I was hoping that Swift 2.0 protocol extensions would allow me to do this - writing the `init?(_ what:Int)` initializer in *one* place and injecting / inheriting it in *both* enums. However, I haven't found a way that works. The problem is that the protocol extension doesn't know that the adopter will *have* an `init(rawValue:)` initializer, and I have not found a way to reassure it.

I suspect that this is because of the automagic way that the `rawValue` initializer comes into existence, and so probably nothing can be done. But perhaps someone has a suggestion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking to extend the `RawRepresentable` protocol:

```
extension RawRepresentable {
    init?(_ what: RawValue) {
        self.init(rawValue: what)
    }
}
```

Any enum with a raw type automatically conforms to `RawRepresentable`, therefore you haven't got to make `E1` or `E2` conform to any extra protocols:

```
enum E1: Int {
    case One = 1, Two
}

enum E2: String {
    case One = "1", Two = "2"
}

let e1 = E1(1)   // .One
let e2 = E2("2") // .Two
```

Comment: Simple but (for me) revolutionary - it just didn't occur to me. Actually, it's even better than that. I can say `extension RawRepresentable where Self:Attribute`, and now I'm doing what I really want to do, which is (1) do this only for certain enums, and (2) keep the ability to subsume my parallel enums under a common type.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work, like this:

```
protocol P {
    var rawValue : Int {get}
    init?(rawValue: Int)
}
extension P {
    init?(_ what:Int) {
        self.init(rawValue:what)
    }
}

enum E1 : Int, P {
    case One, Two
}
enum E2 : Int, P {
    case One, Two
}
```

We use the regular `protocol` declaration to reassure the protocol extension that our adopter will have an `init?(rawValue:)`.

[However, there is still something very odd going on. This code compiles in one of my projects, but not in another. I think it has something to do with how other code *uses* the P protocol; if *no* other code uses the P protocol, all is well, but if other code uses the P protocol, in ways that I have not precisely determined, the code fails to compile, with a mysterious error about the enum not conforming to the protocol.]

Comment: Perhaps you have another protocol named P hiding somewhere in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Dunno what can be wrong. Would be nice to have isolated case. Maybe more generic version helps?

```
protocol BaseRaw {
  typealias T
  var rawValue : T { get }
  init?(rawValue: T)
}

extension BaseRaw {
  init?(_ value: T) {
    self.init(rawValue: value)
  }
}

enum E1 : Int, BaseRaw {
  case One = 1
  case Two = 2
}

enum E2 : String, BaseRaw {
  case One = "1"
  case Two = "2"
}

let e = E1(1)
let e2 = E2("2")

print(e)            // Optional(E1.One)
print(e!.rawValue)  // 1
print(e2)           // Optional(E2.Two)
print(e2!.rawValue) // "2"
```